# Unable to connect nodejs api on localhost:5000 on server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, axios, localhost

I have successfully deployed React app on digitalocean droplet with mongodb.

My server configured with nodejs nginx pm2 and everything is working fine
here is my site

[www.xdomain.ml](https://www.xdomain.ml)

But I build my react app to connect with the backend nodejs api.
I am using socket.io and axios to connect.

everything is working fine on my local computer but it could not connect on the server.

my socket configuration is like

```
const socket = io("localhost:5000")
```

and axios is like

```
axios.post("http://localhost:5000/delete-domains")
```

on browser console, showing

```
polling-xhr.js:198 GET https://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NjNh9TP net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

what I am missing?

do I need to replace the localhost:5000 to 127.0.0.1:5000 on code and build again?

But the mongodb connection successfully establish by

```
"mongodb://localhost:27017/api";
```

please help
Thanks

Comment: looks like you have hosted the website as http and the socket connection is expecting https

Comment: so how can I fix this? thanks

Comment: also localhost will not work after hosting to the server. I hope you have replaced local host with the server ip, and have opened those ports on your server

Comment: but how the mongodb connection working?

Comment: I tried to change my hosting ip but the result are same

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

`const socket = io("localhost:5000")`

to

`const socket = io("http://localhost:5000")`

Or other advance setting:

```js
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost', {
    port: 5000,
    reconnect: true
});
```

Comment: not working. localhost is not recognizing on host. its using my local computer address

Comment: Can you deploy both also on digitalocean? Or you need the static IP address.

Comment: you can change the IP to the one on the digitalocean, if you write localhost in the browser js side it will connect to your computer's localhost.

Answer (score 0):

> const socket = io("localhost:5000")

on this line you are missing "http://" or if you have ssl "https://"
this line should be

> const socket = io("http://localhost:5000");

Comment: http://localhost mean local computer not hosting server